# How often is the GC executed?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Java: How often is the GC executed in JVM? Every second? Every minute? Or is it random depending on the memory size? I just want to have an idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends on the memory usage and the heap in which the objects are stored. Look at this

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html

It does not depend on time. It only depends on the new memory requirements and available memory.

Comment: ...and also of course, the garbage collection options which have been specified!

Comment: @berry....yes but those options do not guarantee that gc will be invoked. It ultimately depends on jvm only.