# Java ResultSet close vs ResultSet set null

Tags: java

After we finish using resultset, normally i will do the following:

```
if(rs != null)
    rs.close();   rs = null;
```

What i want to ask is, by setting resultset = null like the following:

```
if(rs != null)
    rs = null;
```

Does it equals to setting `rs.close()`? Is there any chance that maximum cursor still occur?

Comment: NO! It's not the same. You must close it. I don't get the second question though.

Comment: @Rudy Not duplication, my question is difference between resultset set null versus resultset close, the link you attached is why we need to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it equals to setting rs.close()? Is there any chance that maximum cursor still occur?

No. They're not the same, and simply `null`ing the reference will not close the resources on your database. In fact, when the reference goes out of scope, it's unreachable (and thus `null`ed). So there isn't any need to explicitly `null` the reference. Also, note that without the braces your `null` assignment isn't attached to the `if`.

```
if (rs != null) {
    rs.close();
}
```

Comment: sorry, i intended to put `rs = null;` same line with rs close

Comment: Is setting resultset  to null reduce the workload of GC? I mean, we can free up the memory little bit without having to wait for reference goes out of scope

Comment: @hades No. It's equivalent to letting the variable go out of scope. It makes it *eligible* for GC (that doesn't necessarily invoke GC).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Oh! Really ? Isn't the collector working all the time ? The sooner you set it to null, the sooner it will be able to clean it, won't it ?

Comment: @UDKOX There are [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582209/java-garbage-collector-when-does-it-collect) ways to [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909150/how-often-is-the-gc-executed) that question, but worrying about when (or if) the garbage collector will run is a micro-optimization (and you're probably better off if you [write dumb code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/devinsight-1-139780.html)).

Comment: @UDKOX It will be able to, but that doesn't mean it will. I'll sometimes null out a temporary resource if it's heavy and I need to do some more processing within the same scope. But it's usually unnecessary.